# Use HttpListener to send HTTP trailer in chunked response

Tags: c#, http-headers, httplistener, http-chunked

I Implemented a `HttpListener` to process post requests.  I need to stream data in the response and then send a trailer. [See: HTTP Trailer Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590791/http-chunked-encoding-need-an-example-of-trailer-mentioned-in-spec)

I've gone through the [HttpListenerResponse Source Code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpListenerResponse.cs,08820cfb6e2b9f64) to see if I can use reflection to trick it to send a trailer, which does not seem to be natively supported.

Here is a code sample of what I'm doing.

```
// setup response
_context.Response.SendChunked = true;
_context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
_context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
_context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; // "text/plain";
_context.Response.AddHeader("Trailer", "CRC");

// write bytes to output stream...
WriteStream(_context.Response.OutputStream);

// now what? -- this does not work...
_context.Response.AddHeader("CRC", "a trailer value goes here");

// close the response
_context.Response.Close();
```

Is there a way to do it? direct HttpAPI calls, Reflection, other suggestions...

Comment: How do you envision using this? Most clients don't support trailers and intermediaries are likely to mess them up anyway.

Comment: I have a client that supports this. (Not a browser, though i'm not sure they don't support this feature).  I am looking to send additinal data after streaming and it seems absurd to me that I should add another encoding/decoding layer, when the feature already exists in http.