# Listing of standard HTTP Trailer header names?

Tags: http, http-headers, standards

I've found good documentation for the structure of trailer headers [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer), but I have not been able to find any list of standard HTTP Trailer Header names.

Have these been standardized or codified anywhere?  Are there any APIs that are commonly referenced for the use of trailer headers?  Are there any HTTP trailer headers that are "generally understood" in terms of their meaning?

Some examples of trailer headers seen in the wild:

- `X-Streaming-Error` from [Pivotal blog](http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/http-trailers/)
- `Expires` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer)
- gRPC [provides facilities for using trailer headers to send meta-data in requests](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md), but doesn't provide much guidance on naming conventions
- The [http2 spec](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/) provides the unhelpful example trailer header of `foo`
- This Stackoverflow post uses the example headers `Content-Length` and `Date` ([HTTP Chunked Encoding. Need an example of 'Trailer' mentioned in SPEC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590791/http-chunked-encoding-need-an-example-of-trailer-mentioned-in-spec))
- The Wikipedia page for [Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Applicability) cites 3 names *prohibited* from use as a trailer header: `Transfer-Encoding, Content-Length and Trailer`

Related:

- [Custom HTTP headers : naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions)

Comment: As Trailer header-name indicates additional field of chunked data, it is more like a custom HTTP header and unlikely to have a standard. However, according to MDN, several headers are disallowed.

Comment: Yeah, maybe standard was too strong. Conventions would do quite nicely, though. Really what I'm looking for is a way to communicate errors to the consumer of an HTTP chunked response in the least surprising way possible.